# Time complexity analysis. while loop with inner for loop

Tags: algorithm, time, big-o, complexity-theory

I'm trying to find the number of times this code runs. On the right I have my attempt at the code. I'm am not sure about the loops. Here is the code:

```
                         times
sum = 0                    1
i = 1                      1 
while i ≤ n                log n + 1
 sum = sum + i             n log n
 i = 2i                    log n
return sum                  1
```

=> n log n + 2 log n + 4

and thereby:  O(n log n)

is this correct ?

Comment: Any specific reason for posting pretty much the exact same question again? My guess is the answer posted there didn't fully answer your question, thus you probably shouldn't have accepted it until your question has been fully answered (and certainly not have posted a secondary question to clarify or confirm that answer - that should be done with comments).

Comment: Sorry. edited the code now. My question is still the same, though. I'm trying to figure out the connection in using a "log n" factor instead of "n" factor. Please let me know is this is still ambiguous. thanks for your time

Comment: Then say so in your *question*. and why did you strip of the +1 part of logn+1 from the previous answer (note: technically, you also need rounding)?

Comment: thank you. I edited the " + 1 ". This question is much alike the other time complexity analysis question. The difference is the inner loop. I'm a bit confused about the "n log n" factor and why it is there. hence the question.

Comment: This is not a duplicate from before because there's no for loop nested inside the while loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your analysis is incorrect. Note that each iteration of the inner loop does O(1) work, so the total time complexity can be found by multiplying the number of loop iterations by O(1).

In this case, the loop runs for O(log n) iterations, since i can only double O(log n) times before it exceeds n. Therefore, the total time complexity is O(log n).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. I ran the code , and it shows the sequence is really fast. Thank you !