# time complexity for this algorithm with two for loops

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, nested-loops, binary-search, logarithm

Can you explain me how to find time complexity for this

```
sum1=0;
for(k=1;k<=n;k*=2)
  for(j=1;j<n;j++)
     sum++
```

I am taking consideration of N as base, and tried calculating how many iteration happens when

```
n=1,2,3...n
```

But i am not able to genralize it.
PLease some one explain me, thoroughly.
I have even checked other queries of similar type like: 
saying it follows

```
1,2,4,8...n so it will be
2^n
nlogn
```

But i dint understand.
I dont know how they say `2^n=logn`.
Please any properly explain how to calculate step by step..

Thanks :)

Comment: but my text says : the time complexity is nLogn .Thats why confused

Comment: @JerryCoffin: text says: 
#runs=(1+...N)LogN= Summation of j=1 to logn of (n)
= n logn

Comment: Can you quote the full text for `n log n`. It's difficult to understand your context.

Comment: Hey i am really sorry. The increment was written wrong, I have edited it now

Comment: possible duplicate of [Time complexity analysis. while loop with inner for loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21501752/time-complexity-analysis-while-loop-with-inner-for-loop)

Comment: Ya my question is almost the same. In that query too, he says its O(logn). I want to know the reason.
When,
n=1, while ran 1
n=2, while loop ran 2 times
n=3, while loop ran 2 times
n=4, while loop ran 3 times....
so how are you all deducing it to logn

Comment: if n=2^16, it takes 16 steps. looks logarithm to me ;)

Comment: Ya theoratically its correct. But i am feeling messed up :( 
i feel its O(2^n)

Answer (score 2):

`k` grows exponentially, so it takes `O(log n)` time to reach `n`. Check the definition of [logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm). That's your outer loop.

The inner loop is a straightforward `O(n)`.

Comment: k is growing like 1,2,4,8, .... n
i.e 2^0, 2^1, 2^2 ..... 2^n. Doesnt that mean O(2^n)

Comment: you lare looking for the number of steps. to reach n=2^x, you need x steps. x is log(n).

Comment: what if k was growing 1,3,9,27 .. n, i.e.power of 3. 
the coplexity would remain same as logn ?

Comment: yes. that's within a constant factor in O notation. if you are interested in the math: you can rewrite a logarithm to a different base, check the equations.

Comment: @ndpu: so you comment here an irrelevant thing just because I commented on your answer? grow up, man.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the full complexity of the two loops, you need to multiply the outer loop's by the inner loop's complexity. This is done by thinking of what happens as n gets very large (technically, as n tends to infinity). How many operations would you have to perform in total on the sum, or, alternatively, on the loop variables?

In this case, the outer loop executes `log(n)` times, as k grows exponentially. Exponentially because k doubles in each iteration of the outer loop, so that means that it grows as 2^k, until 2^k gets to n. A note on multiplying the loop variable like this. As per your question in the comments, if you multiply k by 3, you will still get `log(n)`, but it will be log with base-3, as opposed to log with base-2. Asymptotically, bases of logs are not relevant, so you can simply say that it is log(n), ignoring the base. The first loop therefore has an `O(log(n))` complexity. The inner loop is still linear (runs through n times), so if you multiply those you get the `O(n*log(n))` complexity.

**In summary: O(nlogn)**

Comment: Hey i am really sorry. The increment was written wrong, I have edited it now

Comment: So would that be same if k was tripled ? the time complexity would remain logn itself?

Comment: Yes, but log in base-3, as opposed to ld (log base 2). Asymptotically however, both logs are "equivalent" and so we often just say that it's log(n), ignoring the base of the log. Does that make sense?

Comment: thanks @Martin Dinov.
one more thing, What i wanted to know is. 
how did you deduce the 2^i to logn.
i got to know the procedure. But what if i dint know about it.
i thought the time complexity was O(n*(2^i)).

Answer (score 1):

Given your problem structure:

```
sum1=0;
for(k=1;k<=n;k*=2)  // <-- Takes 1+1/2+1/2^2+1/2^3...+1/2^n = O(log(n)) time
   for(j=1;j<n;j++)  // <-- Takes 1+2+3+...+n = O(n) time
      sum++
```

The outer loop increments the value of k by `k*2`, so you are basically ***half-ing*** the search space every time:

```
k = 1*2 = 2 => 1/2^1 time
k = 2*2 = 4 => above + 1/2^2 time
k = 4*2 = 8 => above + 1/2^3 time
k = 8*2 = 16 => above + 1/2^4 time
.   .     .
.   .     .
.   .     .
k = n*2 = 2^n => above + 1/2^n time
```

To put it another way, you are discarding half the elements every time. With that said, you are actually searching an array of size n in

```
1+(1/2)+(1/2^2)+(1/2^3)+...+(1/2^n) time = log(n) time
```

**How did the `log(n)` come?**

Take the analogy with binary tree in which at every node we are branching into two nodes which could be shown as a recurrence relation:

```
T(n) = 2T(n/2)
```

As the search space reduces by 2, as we go further from the root we must reach a ***boundary condition*** when the search space is equal to `1`. The search space size at a depth of k would be `n/2^k` *(similar to what we saw above)*.

On equating the search spaces, our equation becomes:

```
n/2^k = 1
=> n = 2^k

Taking log on both sides:
=> log n = k log 2
=> log n/ log 2 = k

Rearranging:
k = log n base 2.
```

So at the leaf node, the height of the binary tree that we would have traversed would be log(n) base 2. *In our case we are diving the search space by two and traversing our search space in powers of two reaching the end element in `log(n)` time.*

The overall time complexity of both the loops would be in the order of n * log n = **`O(nlog(n))`**.

Answer (score 0):

Since the inner loop is

```
for(j=1;j<n;j++)
```

The inner loop will execute n times for each iteration of the outer loop.  You simply need to know how many times the outer loop executes, and multiply the two values.

k will take on the following values

```
2^0, 2^1, 2^2, ...., 2^i where 2^i < n
```

take the log (base 2) of both sides of the inequality

```
     2^i < n
log(2^i) < log(n)
i*log(2) < log(n)
       i < log(n)
```

The outer loop will execute exactly i + 1 times so the complexity will be O(i*n), but from above, i < log(n), so the complexity will be O(nlogn)

If instead, the inner loop is

```
for(j=1;j<k;j++)
```

Then the inner loop will execute

```
2^0 + 2^1 + ... + 2^i
```

Note how this is a series and not a sequence.  In fact it's the well known [geometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series). The sum of this series is given by

```
a(1 - r^(i + 1))/(1 - r)
```

where a = 1, r = 2, and if you substitute in log(n) for i (it's log(n) from previous analysis), you get

```
2^(log(n) + 1) - 1
```

which is

```
2*n - 1
```

Comment: ohhh. k... 
but what if i dont deduce it by taking log. Because i will not be knowing it.
Is it correct if i write as timecoplexity = O(n*(2^i))

Comment: No, that would make it O(n^2).  I've updated the reasoning for readability.

Comment: what would be the time coplexity of this:
for(k=1;k<=n;k*=2)
  for(j=1;j<=k;j++)
     sum++
For this i thought as 
1. Outer Loop will run logn times
2. Inner Loop will run n times. So total = O(nlogn)
but in text they have given total= O(2n-1).
can you please explain

Comment: Thanks, but still have one doubt.
why did you substitute i to logn

Comment: Hey , got to know about that :P.
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: It's the same i that was used in the section above